# How can I get JLabel's border color

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
jLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
```

How can I check border color after this?

Comment: There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the discussion.

Comment: *"How can I check border color after this?"*  Why would you need to?  Are you incorrectly using this color to store some aspect of a model, or other information?  Don't do that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking the api, I'd say

```
((LineBorder)jLabel.getBorder()).getLineColor();
```